# Does the --local actually do anything when used with git clone [path]?

Tags: git

According to the output of `git help clone` the `--local` option does the following:

```
   --local, -l
       When the repository to clone from is on a local machine, this flag bypasses the normal "Git
       aware" transport mechanism and clones the repository by making a copy of HEAD and everything
       under objects and refs directories. The files under .git/objects/ directory are hardlinked to
       save space when possible.

       If the repository is specified as a local path (e.g., /path/to/repo), this is the default, and
       --local is essentially a no-op. If the repository is specified as a URL, then this flag is
       ignored (and we never use the local optimizations). Specifying --no-local will override the
       default when /path/to/repo is given, using the regular Git transport instead.
```

If I'm reading this correctly, the second paragraph says this option will default to on whenever a local path is given, and will be ignored whenever the given path is not local. So what's the point? How can it even ever have any effect? Is it basically a no-op stub for compatibility with older versions of git when it did something?

Comment: I know one different effect between a "--local" cloned repo and a "--no-local" one. With "--local" it clones dangling objects but with "--no-local" it  doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is leaked technical detail - the way to implement the `--no-X` options. Instead of defining alone `--no-local` there is option `--local` which is noop, but it has `--no-*` version. Same way (though it is not mentioned in help) you can run `git clone --checkout ...` but it would not affect anything because clone checks out by default.

PS: [some long time ago it was not a default](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d5c418ff56645e13bdbd8c9f7d84fdaf7c8494b), so using it did make sense.